# Android get GPS location via Services at specific time

Tags: java, android

I need android background service which get user GPS location on some given time each day twice or thrice a day and this service should always run even if app is closed or device restart i successfully added service in my app which gives me location on location change but i am unable to get location only on some specific time like `[02:00, 05:30, 21:00]`

**This is my Service to track user location**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager m_locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        this.m_locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Service starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO do something useful
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //  Here I offer two options: either you are using satellites or the Wi-Fi services to get user's location
        //  this.m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this); //  User's location is retrieve every 3 seconds
        this.m_locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return TODO;
        }
        this.m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Task destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 01); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc == null)    //  Filtering out null values
            return ;

        Double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        Double lon = loc.getLongitude();
        //        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude = "+lat+ "\nLongitude = "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //    new UpdateLatitudeLongitude(LocationService.this, lat, lon,).execute();

//Calling AsyncTask for upload latitude and longitude
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }






}
```